# Why cypher query not giving single result, but works with multiple in python

Tags: python, cypher

The following query returns the proper result. The link properties of the nodes in a list can be printed:

```
    result = tx.run("MATCH (n:Page) RETURN n.link")
    print([record["link"] for record in result.data()])
```

If I query for one specific node's link property by it's name, the result seems to be empty, [] is printed:

```
    result = tx.run("MATCH (n:Page) WHERE n.name='$name' RETURN n.link", name=name)
    print([record["link"] for record in result.data()])
```

Running the querys on console both works fine. How can I handle a single result?

Comment: what is `tx`? What module do you use?

Comment: Transaction object or something like that. I copied it from the sample code. https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/

Comment: you should add this information in question. More people will see - so maybe more people could help you.

Comment: examples in your link use `$name` without `' '` and maybe this makes difference. `"MATCH (n:Page) WHERE n.name=$name RETURN n.link"`

Comment: you could also use `print()` to check what you have in variable `name` before `tx.run()` - maybe it has different value then you expect.